# Android Database - Write and Read from Server

Tags: android, database

I need to design an Android application that stores a database on a device and a copy of that database on a server.  This application also needs the ability to query the information based on username, date, and three other parameters.  What is the easiest way to go about this?  I'm new to programming and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- To create Database in your Device you can use Sqlite.Refer [Android Documentation for Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).
- Also create a copy of this database on your server and sync these Server Database and Local Database.
- (Or) you can use [Syncing to the Cloud](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html) google cloud storage and sync the local device database and cloud database.